# AWS EKS cluster node is failing to join the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

AWS EKS cluster (1.27) node is failing to join the cluster and node group is failed and showing below errors.

failed to contact api server when waiting for csinode publishing.
Eviction manager failed to get node info

Looking for fix for this issue as I'm doing testing in of AWS EKS cluster

Comment: are you using a CSI driver? could be an IAM issue. i'd also check to see if the VPC CNI is starting (aws-node).

Comment: This is policy attached with Node role and we are provisioning new node group either in public and private subnet , each one has internet accessibility. I also executed System manager runbook for node troubleshooting but there is error was showing there.  Node role policies are:            
 AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy    @Jeremy Cowan

Comment: Detailed logs as below:                                                                          kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Unauthorized" node="ip-10-10-4-88.ec2.internal"
Aug 6 12:20:16 ip-10-10-4-88 kubelet: E0806 12:20:16.953667  3002 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Unauthorized" interval="7s"
Aug 6 12:20:21 ip-10-10-4-88 kubelet: E0806 12:20:21.012483  3002 eviction_manager.go:262] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"ip-10-10-4-88.ec2.internal\" not found"

Comment: Do you have any role attached to the cluster itself? You should have `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy` attached to the cluster.

Comment: We have created Role for EKS cluster itself and also authenticated through my bastion host properly but Node is still failing: and trust policy is                                                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"     @OguzhanAygun

Comment: It seems you got new error, can you post the whole error? If it's related with the trust policy, can you add trust policy to the EKS role?

Comment: arn="arn:aws:iam::707318434536:role/eksnodegrouprole" client="127.0.0.1:49444" error="mapper EKSConfigMap renderTemplates error: error rendering username template \"system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}\": failed querying private DNS from EC2 API for node i-066f8e944c9ed8324: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 84fd24bb-78ea-4a75-94f8-e75f222262b1 " method=POST path=/authenticate

Comment: Do you think any additional trust policy is required apart default one in nodegroup role @Oguzhan Aygun    Its seems some issue related to AWS-auth so accordingly I've modified and now It's resolved

Comment: Unable to register node with API server" err="Unauthorized" node="ip-10-10-4-88.ec2.internal" Aug 6 12:20:16 ip-10-10-4-88 kubelet: E0806 12:20:16.953667 3002 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Unauthorized" interval="7s" Aug 6 12:20:21 ip-10-10-4-88 kubelet: E0806 12:20:21.012483 3002 eviction_manager.go:262] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"ip-10-10-4-88.ec2.internal\" not found  @Oguzhan Aygun this is error logs now

Comment: very likely an IAM issue. your nodes need AmazonEC2ContainerRegistry, ReadOnly, AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy, and AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy. You can move the AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy to the aws-node DaemonSet if you use IRSA. If your permissions are correct, it could be a security group issue.